# Show that a subset $U$ of a space $ X $ is open if, and only if...

Tags: general-topology

Show that a subset $U$ of a space $ X $ is open if, and only if, $A \cap U = \emptyset$ implies that
$\overline{A} \cap U = \emptyset$ for each $A \subset X$.

I have tried to do a part of this test using the fact that $U \subset A^{c} = X-A$ and trying to prove that the $U$ plugin is closed. However I have not reached the conclusion. Therefore, I would like to know a suggestion or a more sophisticated test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U$ is open, then $U^c$ is closed. Further, if $A \cap U = \emptyset$, then $A \subseteq U^c$, i.e. $U^c$ is a closed superset of $A$. By definition of $\overline{A}$, we have $\overline{A} \subseteq U^c$, i.e. $\overline{A} \cap U = \emptyset$.

Conversely, suppose that $A \cap U = \emptyset \implies \overline{A} \cap U = \emptyset$. In particular, consider $A = U^c$. Then $\overline{U^c} \cap U = \emptyset$, i.e. $\overline{U^c} \subseteq U^c$. As always, we also have $U^c \subseteq \overline{U^c}$, so $U^c = \overline{U^c}$, which is closed. Hence, $U$ is open.